# Beep upon using a mapping

Tags: key-bindings, autocmd

Well, I try to use the following convention. 
± (as unused key) is used for increase search where / is used for regular search.

The implementation:

```
set noincsearch

nmap  ± <esc>:set incsearch<CR>/

augroup vimrc-noincsearch-highlight
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdlineLeave / :set noincsearch |  :noh 
augroup END
```

Everything works fine.

The only tiny problem is that I get a beep every time I use it!

I tried to use other keys as well, but I get the same anonying beep.

Temporary solution:

```
set visualbell t_vb=
```

Help?

Thanks.

Comment: The beep is probably from `<esc>`; does it work if you remove that and use `nnoremap` ?

Comment: Will post answer later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nmap  ± <esc>:set incsearch<CR>/
```

`<Esc>` in *normal mode* issues a beep. Your `:nmap` is a normal mode mapping; no `<esc>` is necessary here. You could use `<C-u>` to swallow any accidental `[count]`, though. And [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion:

```
nnoremap  ± :<C-u>set incsearch<CR>/
```

Though not needed here, there is a special mapping that ensures normal mode without a beep: [`:help CTRL-\_CTRL-N`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#CTRL-%5C_CTRL-N)

> Additionally the command CTRL-\ CTRL-N or  can be used to go to
>   Normal mode from any other mode.  This can be used to make sure Vim is in
>   Normal mode, without causing a beep like  would.  However, this does not
>   work in Ex mode.