# Alert sound when using <C-L> etc. mappings

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, comments

I've got these mappings in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-Tab> :tabn<cr>  " cycle tabs
nnoremap <C-S-Tab> :tabp<cr>    " cycle tabs backward

nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>   " no Ctrl-W needed to navigate up
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>   " no Ctrl-W needed to navigate down
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>   " no Ctrl-W needed to navigate right
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>   " no Ctrl-W needed to navigate left
```

When I use them (e.g. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>), they work, but I get a “bong” alert sound.

I get the sound in Windows (GVim 8.1 on Win 10), and in my terminal (Vim 8.1 on CentOS via SecureCRT).
There's no sound when I enter the commands manually (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>), with or without the `nnoremap` in place.
There's no sound when I use those key combos in other programs.

Why is that happening, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Side note, a few of those mappings may be more than one thing (Ctrl-H is sometimes backspace, Ctrl-L a screen redraw, and Ctrl-J a newline like hitting Enter)

Comment: Good to know. In normal mode, C-H and C-J are redundant (for my purposes). Screen redraw is sometimes handy, though.

Comment: When I come to think about it, it is possible that there is no window below your window and that is why it beeps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bad habit to do spaces and remarks in the same line of the mapping. I believe it includes them in the mapping and it causes the beep(about the remark I am not sure). So try to remove them and see what happens.

I have asked a similar question [Beep upon using a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17737/beep-upon-using-a-mapping) .

As a temporary solution:

`set visualbell t_vb=`

Disables all beeps

Comment: You're so right!
I forgot to include the pipe. Changed to e.g. `nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>|  " no Ctrl-W needed to navigate up` and there are no bells. (Also no bell if I remove everything after the last `>`.)